# Any app to turn off screen of a laptop?

Tags: display, system, battery

Complete newbie here, just installed EOS for its aesthetics, it's one great looking OS,

I have always been using the screen off software to turn off my screen in windows os, is there a app like that for this OS?

Or can anyone tell me an alternative method to turn off the screen?

Answer (score 1):

For that I have a separate folder in my home folder - `scripts`

I have a file for that - `~/scripts/turnscreenoff.sh` which contents are:

`#!/bin/bash
sleep 0.15; xset dpms force off`

sleep is needed because of keyup event that can wake up screen.

All you need now is to make the script executable:

`chmod +x ~/scripts/turnscreenoff.sh` and assign a keyboard shortcut to that script in keyboard settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it.

Create an executable file with the following text:

sleep 1
light-locker-command -a

Then make a desktop file where the exec line point to the file above and put it on the .local/share/applications/ folder.

This will turn off the monitor, but if you have the option to lock the screen after the monitor turns off it will also lock the screen.

If you don't mind to lock the screen after the monitor turns off, simply use the shortcut super+l. This will turn the monitor off and lock the screen.